# HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, netflix-eureka

I added below dependency to my web service

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Now I get below issue in my code don't know what is going wrong. Befor adding this dependency it was working fine.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.slb.sis.seisstream.job.dropbox.pollers.psdc.model.JobGroup$Job` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2D_2D_Pre_sd_sds'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.slb.sis.seisstream.job.dropbox.pollers.psdc.model.JobGroup$Job` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2D_2D_Pre_sd_sds')
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 41, column: 25] (through reference chain: com.slb.sis.seisstream.job.dropbox.pollers.psdc.model.JobGroup["job"]->java.util.ArrayList[2])
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:245)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:204)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:157)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.slb.sis.seisstream.job.dropbox.pollers.psdc.model.JobGroup$Job` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2D_2D_Pre_sd_sds')
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 41, column: 25] (through reference chain: com.slb.sis.seisstream.job.dropbox.pollers.psdc.model.JobGroup["job"]->java.util.ArrayList[2])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
```

below is full pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.slb.prosource</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProSource-JMF</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>1</id>
            <url>http://129.87.7.240:8081/repository/maven-public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>2</id>
            <url>http://163.183.188.25:8081/repository/maven-public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.xml</groupId> <artifactId>jaxp-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.4.2</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.slb.psl</groupId>
            <artifactId>PS-Logs</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <!--<exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId> </exclusion> <exclusion> <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId> 
                <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId> </exclusion> <exclusion> <groupId>groovy</groupId> 
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId> </exclusion> <exclusion> <groupId>com.google.gson</groupId> 
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId> </exclusion> &lt;!&ndash;<exclusion> <groupId>j2ee</groupId> 
                <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId> </exclusion>&ndash;&gt; </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- indirect -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.slb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProSource-Tahiti</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.slb.reef</groupId>
            <artifactId>Reef-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.slb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProSource-Coral</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>j2ee</groupId>
                    <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.slb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProSource-Registrymgr</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.slb.federator</groupId>
            <artifactId>Federator-Build</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.slb.pss</groupId>
            <artifactId>PS-Seismic</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>   javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- indirect End -->


    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- <exclude>application.properties</exclude> <exclude>TahitiConfig.xml</exclude> 
                        <exclude>job_definitions.xml</exclude> -->
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

</project>
```

I don't understand what is going wrong

Answer (score 2):

Just add a constructor with a string parameter on your entity/pojo class and jackson should be able to to deserialize your json.

If not working can you edit your post to add the json and the class `JobGroup`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. It was working before just because I added one more dependency it is failing. if I remove that than it is working fine

Comment: That's maybe because `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server` provide an http converter different provided by spring-boot

Answer (score 2):

After Martin's suggestion I excluded below dependency and it is working now

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks Martin for prompt response

Answer (score 0):

> The class should have the following
>
> 1. Empty Constructor (without any arguments)
> 2. Setter functions (for the field variables).

I use lombok and had only `@Getter`, `@Setter`, `@AllArgsConstructor`. But I was still getting this error.

The code for mapping creates an object first using the empty constructor (`@NoArgsConstructor`) first and then populates the values using the setters.

So I added the `@NoArgsConstrutor` (which is nothing but lombok's way of adding an empty constructor) and it worked perfectly.